# Synthetic control method

Tags: r, synth

I want to perform a synthetic control method in R. I have come across several packages, but these are all archived. (Synth and Tidysynth are two of these) Does someone know which available package I can use to perform a synthetic control method?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.